# Problem with Dropdown: test passed but there's no changes on a page

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have a code for option selection in dropdown and it Passed. But  there is no changes on the page. I have an ordinary dropdown: have to choose a country from country-dropdown and state from state-dropdown.

I guess I tried Everything suggested on stackoverflow. But What did I miss?

This code is ordinary:

```
<div class="input-holder">
<select name="country" id="country" class="jcf-hidden">
<option value="GBR">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="USA" selected="selected">United States</option>
```

My code is:

```
it("should edit dropdown", () => {

let country = element(by.id("country"));
let countryOptions = country.all(by.tagName("option"));
let state = element(by.id("state_select"));
let stateOptions = state.all(by.tagName("option"));

countryAndStateSelection();

function countryAndStateSelection() {
    countryOptions.getText().then(text => {
        if(text === "United States"){
            countryOptions.get(217).click(); //UK
            stateOptions.get(19).click();
            expect(countryOptions.getText()).toEqual("United Kingdom"); 
        }else{
            countryOptions.get(218).click(); //USA
            stateOptions.get(5).click();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you have problem with choosing option from dropdown.
That's correct. You don't open the dropdown, so the valeus are not visible, yet.

Here you have a bit cleaned up code:

```
it("should edit dropdown", () => {
    let country = element(by.id("country"));
    let state = element(by.id("state_select"));

    countryAndStateSelection('United States', 'Alaska');
    // add your expect here

    function countryAndStateSelection(countryToSelect, stateToSelect) {
        selectCountry(countryToSelect);
        selectState(stateToSelect);
    }       

    function selectCountry(countryToSelect) {
        country.click();
        element(by.cssContainingText('#country option'), countryToSelect).click();
    }

    function selectState(stateToSelect) {
        state.click();
        element(by.cssContainingText('#state_select option'), stateToSelect).click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
let country = element(by.id("country"));
let state = element(by.id("state_select"));
//To select country
country.click();
element(by.cssContainingText('#country>option', 'User country name here')).click();
browser.sleep(2000);
state.click();
element(by.cssContainingText('#state_select>option', 'user State Name')).click();
browser.sleep(2000);
```

Hope it helps you